# Given $\triangle ABC$ with $C=60^\circ$, show that $\frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}=\frac{3}{a+b+c}$

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

> Given that $C=60^\circ$ on a triangle $ABC$, prove the following relation: $$\frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}=\frac{3}{a+b+c}$$

P.S. Maybe this info could be of help: I used the cosine rule of triangles, given that $C=60°$.

Comment: I'm assuming that $a, b, c$ are the legs and $A, B, C$ are the angles, right?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You should show the work you've done. Perhaps there was a minor error that will be easy to spot, or someone can nudge you toward a complete solution. In any case, such information helps people avoid wasting time (theirs and yours) telling you things you already know, duplicating your effort, or using techniques with which you aren't yet familiar.

Comment: @N.Bar Yeah, and $a, b, c$ are opposites to $A, B,$ and $C$ respectively.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $(a+b+c)(a+c)(b+c)$ to remove the fractions and simplify.  How does this expression compare to the implication $C = 60^\circ$ has through the law of cosines?

Comment: https://brainly.in/question/6031851

Comment: It is nice really. I was wrong believing that it was not relevant. I guess it could be other nice formulas for particular values of an angle. For $60^º$ we could build problems for an arbitrary cevian in equilateral triangles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try to simplify the expression $\frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}=\frac{3}{a+b+c}$.

Multiply through by $a + b + c$ and you obtain the equivalent expression
$$\frac{a+b+c}{a+c} + \frac{a + b + c}{b + c} = 3$$
This is equivalent to
$$\frac{b}{a+c} + \frac{a}{b + c} = 1$$
Multiplying through by $(a+c)(b+c)$ this is the same as
$$b(b+c) + a(a + c) = (a + c)(b+c)$$
Expanding out this becomes
$$b^2 + bc + a^2 + ac = ab + cb + ac + c^2$$
Cancelling terms this becomes
$$b^2 + a^2 - ab = c^2$$
This is exactly what the law of cosines gives you.

Comment: Thanks, this would wonderfully suffice!